# Multiple tags$textarea boxes within renderUI function shiny

Tags: textbox, shiny

I have a shiny app that conducts t-test between two independent samples.  Based on a radio button choice, you can either input summary statistics (\bar{x}, sd, n) for both samples, or you can copy/paste or type in the values of each sample.  The renderUI function looks something like this:

```
    output$ui<-renderUI({
      switch(input$option,
             "Summary Stats" = 
               c(textInput("barx1","$$\\bar{x}_1$$", "0"),
                 textInput("picksd1", "$$sd_1$$", "1"),
                 textInput("n1","$$n_1$$","10"),
                 textInput("barx2", "$$\\bar{x}_2$$","1"),
                 textInput("picksd2", "$$sd_2$$","1"),
                 textInput("n2","$$n_2$$","10")),
             "Input Data" = c(tags$textarea(id="foo1", rows=10, cols=38), tags$textarea(id="foo2", rows=10, cols=38)))
    })
```

The textInputs render and work fine in the UI, but the text boxes don't, any help here?  I have something very similar for a one sample case, where foo1 works fine, the problem seems to be that I want two text boxes and maybe that I have them stored in c() form, though this works fine for the textInputs.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make this work by using html code instead of "tags".  Not sure why tags$textarea didn't work when used in c(tags$textarea, tags$textarea) form but this looks a lot cleaner anyway:

```
    output$ui<-renderUI({
switch(input$option,
       "Summary Stats" = HTML(
         '<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
           <label for="barx1">$$\\bar{x}_1$$</label>
           <input id="barx1" type="text" class="form-control" value="0"/>
           </div>
         <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
           <label for="picksd1">$$sd_1$$</label>
          <input id="picksd1" type="text" class="form-control" value="1"/>
          </div>
         <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
           <label for="n1">$$n_1$$</label>
         <input id="n1" type="text" class="form-control" value="10"/>
         </div>
        <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
          <label for="barx2">$$\\bar{x}_2$$</label>
         <input id="barx2" type="text" class="form-control" value="1"/>
         </div> 
        <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
          <label for="picksd2">$$sd_2$$</label>
         <input id="picksd2" type="text" class="form-control" value="1"/>
         </div> 
        <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
          <label for="n2">$$n_2$$</label>
         <input id="n2" type="text" class="form-control" value="10"/>
         </div>' 
       ),
       "Input Data" = HTML(
         '<div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
              <label for="foo1">Sample 1</label>
         <textarea id="foo1" rows="10" cols="38"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
         <label for="foo2">Sample 2</label>
         <textarea id="foo2" rows="10" cols="38"></textarea>
         </div>'
       ))   
      })
```